# Intento logearme en una API REST mediante curl

Tags: php, login, rest, curl

Estoy intentando logearme en un servicios REST para poder obtener un token que me va a servir para generar una consulta, pero no logro hacerlo. estoy intentando con este codigo, el cual me tira el ERROR 404

esta es la pagina del loggin
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrlvN.jpg

````
$processLoginURL = 'https://pruebas-contap-279823.appspot.com/generateToken';
$username = '97151300_partner_2';
$password = 'V+&y&vTfzitzSDkI';
$ch = curl_init($processLoginURL);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    "username=$username&password=$password");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/cookies.txt' );
$res = curl_exec( $ch );
echo curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $error = curl_error( $ch ) ) {
    die ($error);
}
echo $res;
curl_close( $ch );```
````

Comment: Verifica la URL ya que el error dice que no se ha encontrado la página

Comment: Es posible que el problema sea en `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username&password=$password");`? Fíjate que no estás pasando `$username`.

Comment: ya lo arregle lo del username y no, sigue mostrando error 404

Answer (score 1):

logre resolverlo por si alguien mas le sirve. instalan las librerias de composer "auth0" y "vlucas" no se cual de las dos funciono junto con este codigo,

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://your.url';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  
echo($result);
```